# Order resultset by the most common value within group

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have my table like this:

```
 current | similar
   8     |2
   8     |4
   8     |4
   8     |4
   8     |4
   8     |5
   8     |5
```

but I want in this way the 4 first because it repeats 4 times, 5 second cuz repeats twice and finally 2 once:

```
 current | similar
   8     |4
   8     |4
   8     |4
   8     |4
   8     |5
   8     |5
   8     |2
```

I have tried with:
`select * from mytable order by similar`, but I get the 5 first the 4 second and the 2 last

also:

```
select * from mytable order by count(similar) but only one row is returned
```

finally:
`select *, count(similar) as a from mytable order by a`, but nothing even with group by doesn't work, how do I achieve it? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you can count occurrences of each `similar` field within `current` group and then `join` it with the original table to sort the result set.

```
select t1.current, t1.similar
from tbl t1
join (
    select current, similar, count(*) as ttl
    from tbl
    group by current, similar
) t2 on t1.current = t2.current and t1.similar = t2.similar
order by t1.current, t2.ttl desc
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28dac/1)

Comment: I just finished typing this same query when you answer popped up.